# Set up LDAP on Redmine with Zimbra LDAP

Tags: ldap, openldap, redmine, zimbra

I'm trying to enable LDAP authentication for a Redmine installation. My LDAP Server is the one provided by Zimbra, and I'm perfectly sure that it works good (I use LDAP also for ownCloud server, in the same machine of Redmine).
Anyway, with the same configuration, it doesn't work on Redmine.

It says "Successful connection", but I get "0 users"; and if I try to login with my LDAP credentials it gives me a login error.

Anyone has ever tested Redmine with Zimbra auth on LDAP? Here's my configuration:
[image]

P.s: Besides; I currently have some users directly registered on Redmine before setting up LDAP. Can I directly link these users to their LDAP account, or I need to create a new account?

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar issue. You have the fields mixed up

**LDAP filter**: should be empty because there is some kind of issue between the Zimbra LDAP filter and Redmine's.

**Account**: `uid=zimbra,cn=admins,cn=zimbra`

**Password**: The password you entered for LDAP during installation

**Base DN**: `ou=people,dc=domain,dc=com` (replace domain for your domain and com for your extension)

**LDAP Filter**: empty

**Timeout**: empty

**On the fly user creation**: empty (didn't try it)

**Login attribute**: `uid`

**Firstname attribute**: `givenName`

**Lastname attribute**: `sn`

**Email attribute**: `email`

To clarify and expand on the answer above, you need this parameters in **Account** because you are using the **zimbra** user and password for the LDAP directory connection. This could be another user with the right permissions or you could even allow (but don't!) anonymous browsing/query of the LDAP server.

You should use another user if you are giving Redmine administrator to people you don't trust and don't want them to know the root ldap password, but this will do just fine if you are the administrator of both systems.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the `LDAP filter` to `uid=zimbra...` is obviously wrong, as you would limit the search to exactly that user.

This filter can be used to limit the search to things like user groups or a sub-`ou`. Leave it empty.

It might be that you need to use the `uid=zimbra` part (or just `zimbra`) in the `Account` field if it needs administrative access to the LDAP database. I don't know Redmine, but most systems shouldn't need this and just authenticate with the username/password the user entered to validate the account.